# How to fix 'The method mismatch(int[], int[]) is undefined for the type Arrays'

Tags: java

I'm currently learning about Array methods, but struggling with the `mismatch(...)`-method. 
The compiler always throws me the unresolved compilation problem: The method `mismatch(int[], int[])` is undefined for the type Arrays, although both of the passed arguments are of the type `int[]`

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {


        int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3};

        System.out.println(Arrays.mismatch(a, b));

    }

}
```

I expect the printed output to be `-1`, but I get the described error.

Comment: Does `Arrays` really have a method `mismatch`?

Comment: Which version of java are you using?

Comment: `mismatch` has been introduced with Java 9, as you can see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#mismatch-int:A-int:A- Make sure that you are also running this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method mismatch(int[], int[]) is undefined for the type Arrays

You can check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#mismatch-int:A-int:A-).
This method requires **java 9.**